# Flutter SingleChildScrollView is not stopping in the middle but bouncing to the edge

Tags: flutter, scrollview

In demo, even if I don't use drawer or appBar it doesn't matter. Any scrollview is not stopping in the middle. Even if it's a ListView or column in a SingleChildScrollView, it doesn't matter. I can't scroll normally. It suddenly bounces to the other edge.

The reason I use option + shift is to show when I release mouse.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqlQL_rl3Xc

Test Demo:

```
import 'xxxx/widgets/app-bar.dart';
import 'xxxx/widgets/drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageHome extends StatefulWidget {
  PageHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageHomeState createState() => _PageHomeState();
}

class _PageHomeState extends State<PageHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: IAppBar(
        title: "Home",
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(
        index: AppDrawer.DRAWER_INDEX_HOME,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: ScrollController(),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                Colors.yellow,
                Colors.teal,
                Colors.purple,
                Colors.blue,
                Colors.red
              ])),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(height: 3000),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } f
}
```

Main dart:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp();

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'CT',
        theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          primaryColor: primaryColor,
          accentColor: accentColor,
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.ubuntuTextTheme().copyWith(
              headline1: GoogleFonts.ubuntuTextTheme().headline1?.copyWith(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  color: Colors.black)),
        ),
        onGenerateRoute: ARouter.generateRoute);
  }
}

class Splash extends StatefulWidget {
  const Splash({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashState createState() => _SplashState();
}

class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
      if ((!await FlutterSecureStorage().containsKey(key: "intro"))) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, ARouter.routeIntro);
        return;
      }
      if (await getJWT() == null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, ARouter.routeAuth);
        return;
      }
      if (await validateToken())
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, ARouter.routeHome);
      else
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, ARouter.routeAuth);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Image.asset("assets/images/bg.png"),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircularProgressIndicator(
                strokeWidth: 6,
              ),
              Container(height: 24),
              Center(
                  child: Text(
                "Loading",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.none),
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the app on a real device? I noticed the same behaviour when using the emulator, but everything is fine when testing on the device.

Comment: It acts same on Flutter 2.0.6, 2.2.0, 2.2.1. But as you said problem occurs on simulators. When I launch it on my physical device it works flawlessly. All of my projects' scroll views gain velocity when I drag a little while on simulator.